# how can a pixel in a bitmap can be deleted?

Tags: c++

i m decreasing the resolution of a bitmap. i found a method on a site which is as follows

Average the values of all surrounding pixels, store that value in the choosen pixel location, then delete all the surrounding pixels.so a 4*6 matrix becomes a 4 x 3 matrix.

i am accessing pixels by this code

```
for(int y = 0; y < bmp.bmHeight; y++)   
  {      
      for(int x = 0; x < bmp.bmWidth; x++)     
      {         
          COLORREF rgb = dc.GetPixel(x, y);     
          BYTE r = GetRValue(rgb);       
          BYTE g = GetGValue(rgb);     
          BYTE b = GetBValue(rgb);            
          dc.SetPixel(x, y, RGB(r,g,b));      
      }   
  }
```

tell me how can i delete a pixel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really delete a pixel, a bitmap is a matrix of pixels. Rather, you should make a new bitmap of the intended size, and copy pixels into that.

Comment: oh i see. can u plz show me how to make a new bitmap of intended size and copy pixels into that?

Comment: That depends on what library you're using. So maybe you could tell that ;-)

Comment: i m using MFC. this is a part of my code. CBitmap img;   
  CDC dc;  
  BITMAP bmp;  
  img.LoadBitmapW(IDB_BIT);   
  img.GetBitmap(&bmp);   
  CDC* pDC = this->GetDC();   
  dc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);  
  CBitmap* pOld = dc.SelectObject(&img);